# Best practice for string substitution with gettext using Python

Tags: python, string, gettext, string-formatting

Looking for best practice advice on what string substitution technique to use when using gettext(). Or do all techniques apply equally?

I can think of at least 3 string techniques:

1) Classic "%" based formatting:

"My name is %(name)s" % locals()

2) .format() based formatting:

"My name is {name}".format( locals() )

3) string.Template.safe_substitute()

import string
template = string.Template( "My name is ${name}" )
template.safe_substitute( locals() )

The advantage of the string.Template technique is that a translated string with with an incorrectly spelled variable reference can still yield a usable string value while the other techniques unconditionally raise an exception. The downside of the string.Template technique appears to be the inability for one to customize how a variable is formatted (padding, justification, width, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I would *prefer* to get an exception during my tests, to fix the error as soon as possible -- "errors should not pass silently".  So I consider that approach (2) is the best one in modern Python (which supports the readable and flexible `format`), and approach (1) a probably inevitable fall-back if you're stuck supporting older Python releases (where `%` was "the" way to do flexible formatting -- finding, or coding, some backport of `format` would be the main alternative).

Comment: Alex: Thanks for your answer. We had a small section of code that was using user customizable strings as a pseudo template facility, hence my attraction to the string.Template technique. We're going to bite the bullet and use a real template module for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have incorrectly spelled variable names - that's what testing is for.

On the face of it, displaying *something* seems better than throwing an exception, but sooner or later one of those mistranslations is bound to cause offence to some user.

`.format()` is the way to go these days.

Reconsider passing `locals()` straight into the translation. It will save you worrying about what happens if someone works out a way to do something sneaky with `self` in one of the translations.

Comment: Gnibbler: Thanks for the reminder about locals(). Originally I used locals() as a quick and dirty way to explain my question. However, your comment caused me to go back and do a quick code review to make sure this coding practice hadn't creeped into our code. To my surprise there were several places where we had actually used such a technique.